# Java Generic Interface vs Generic Methods, and when to use one

Tags: java, generics, methods, interface, parameterized

I was wondering, aside from syntactic difference, when would one use a generic interface over a method that accepts a generic parameter?

```
public interface Flight<T>{
   void fly(T obj);
}
```

over

```
public interface Flight{
    void <T> fly(T obj);
}
```

Comment: Do you want one insatnce implementing `flight` to be able to handle in `fly` method only one selected type of data or any type of data?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you declare a generic *method*, you always let the *caller* decide, which type arguments to use for the type parameters. The implementation of the method must be able to deal with all possible types arguments (and it doesn’t even have a way to ask for the actual type arguments).

That said, a method like `<T> void fly(T obj);` states that the caller may use any type for `T` while the only thing the implementation can rely on is that the actual type for `T` will be assignable to `Object` (like if `<T extends Object>` had been declared).

So in this specific example, it’s not different to the declaration `void fly(Object obj);`, which also allows arbitrary objects.

In contrast, a type parameter on an *`interface`* is part of the contract and may be specified or restricted by an *implementation* of the `interface`:

```
public interface Flight<T>{
   void fly(T obj);
}
```

allows implementations like

```
public class X implements Flight<String> {
   public void fly(String obj) {
   }
}
```

fixing the type of `T` on the implementation side. Or

```
public class NumberFlight<N extends Number> implements Flight<N> {
   public void fly(N obj) {
   }
}
```

being still generic but *restricting* the type.

---

The signature of an `interface` is also important when the `interface` itself is a part of another method signature, e.g.

```
public void foo(Flight<? super String> f) {
    f.fly("some string value");
}
```

here, the `Flight` implementation, which you pass to `foo`, must be capable of consuming a `String` value, so `Flight<String>` or `Flight<CharSequence>` or `Flight<Object>` are sufficient, but not `Flight<Integer>`. Declaring such a contract requires type parameters on the `interface`, not at the `interface`’s methods.

Comment: therefore, using the generic interface approach over generic method still boils down to a design decision. It makes sense, adding generic types to the equation doesn't really change what methods and interfaces do, although it adds certain functionalities like type restriction. `NumberFlight` can even restrict the type without changing the contract between `Flight` and `<T>`. That's interesting. I'm more enlightened now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a generic type when you expect that most of the methods, in the implementations, will perform operations on the type supplied when instantiating the class.

For example, `ArrayList<E>` is a generic type since most of its operations (add, get, remove etc.) rely on the type specified upon creation of one.

A generic method should be used when only a few methods in the class rely upon the different types.

You can read more about generics in the [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

Answer (score 0):

Take for example the class `java.util.ArrayList<E>`. When creating variables of that type, you have to specify a concrete type for `T`:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

These concrete types are used, when calling methods from the `List` interface, that work with the type `T`. Calling the `add` method, you can only add `String` objects to the list. Retrieving elements from the list using `get`, you will get elements of the concrete type `String`.

For generic methods, the type `T` is specified only for this method. And it would make more sense if the methods returns a value of that generic type. You often find code like this:

```
MyObject obj = SomeClass.staticGenericMethod(MyObject.class)
```

or

```
MyObject obj = classInstance.genericMethod(MyObject.class);
```

And you should start your interface name with a capital letter: `Flight<T>`