# return type of generic, when to use <T>returnType<T> and when to just use returnType<T>?

Tags: java, generics, return-type

In generic api, why sometimes a type parameter is written before the return type and sometimes it needs not?

Given the following two Steam API as example

```
Stream<T>   limit(long maxSize)
```

and

```
<R> Stream<R>   map(Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper)
```

Why `Stream.limit`'s return type can just be written as `Stream<T>` but not `<T> Stream<T>`?

When to use `<T> returnType <T>` and when to use `returnType<T>`?

Comment: I think it will help going through the answers on [Java Generic Interface vs Generic Methods, and when to use one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575434/java-generic-interface-vs-generic-methods-and-when-to-use-one). The core of your question may in fact make a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `<R>` in `<R> Stream<R>` is just another part of the method signature - the type parameters. You shouldn't view `<R> Stream<R>` as "one" thing, as you seem to have done in your question title.

The first `<R>` is just there to tell you what the type parameters of this method are, so `map` is a generic method. `limit` is not a generic method, because it does not have this part in its signature.

You might be confused about `limit` isn't a generic method, since it clearly returns something that has a generic parameter `T` in it. Well, `T` is actually the generic parameter of the enclosing class `Stream<T>`, so `limit` can't really return any other type than the `Stream<T>` on which it was called. If you call `limit` on a `Stream<A>`, you can't expect it to give you a `Stream<B>`. Therefore, `limit` is not generic.

Note that `T` is also used the parameter list of `map`.

> when to use `<T>returnType<T>` and when to just use `returnType<T>`?

The big difference here is `<T> returnType<T>` makes the method generic. `returnType<T>` is not a generic method, and can only be used if `T` actually *exists* in the context.

Comment: then for method "static <T> Stream<T> concat(Stream<? extends T> a, Stream<? extends T> b)", if <T> is already declared in Stream Interface, why still need the first <T> in <T>Stream<T>?

Comment: @user1169587 Because static methods can't use the class's type parameter. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936377/static-method-in-a-generic-class

Answer (score 5):

The `T` in the first example is the generic parameter of the `Stream` one is operating on, thus `limit(...)` returns a new `Stream` of same generic type like the stream one calls `limit(...)` on.

In the second example, the generic type of the resulting `Stream` may be changed, thus a separate generic parameter is needed. in this case, the type of the resulting `Stream` is influenced by the `mapper`-lambda. If `Person`s are mapped to their `SocialSecurityNumber`, for example, then the initial `Stream` would be a `Stream<Person>`, the `mapper` would be of type `Function<Person, SocialSecurityNumber>` and the resulting `Stream` would be a `Stream<SocialSecurityNumber>`.