# Feasibility of making an interface Functional Interface

Tags: java, java-8

I have this interface

```
public interface CopyData {
    <T extends SpecificRecordBase> void copy(T data);
}
```

I have class implementing this interface

```
public class CopyDataImpl implements CopyData {
    private CopyDataProvider copyDataProvider;

    @Override
    public <T extends SpecificRecordBase> void copy(T data) {
        try {
            Copier copier = copyDataProvider.copyFor(data);
            if(copier == null) {
                return;
            }
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Encoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(data.getSchema(), byteStream);
            data.customEncode(encoder);
            encoder.flush();
            copier.copy(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error occurred storing the data {}", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Spring and loading their beans respectively.

```
@Configuration
public class CopyDataDynamicConfig {

    @Bean
    public CopyDataProvider copyDataProvider() {
        return new CopyDataProviderImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public CopyData copyData(CopyDataProvider copyDataProvider) {
        return new CopyDataImpl(copyDataProvider);
    }

}
```

I want to make my interface a functional interface and use it. Is it feasible or an overkill in this case?

Can someone please share how I can achieve that?

### EDIT 1

I am aware that I can make my interface functional interface easily as it has only method and can add `@FunctionalInterface` annotation.

My question was I want to use functional interface directly and not using dedicated implementation class.

Comment: Given it has a single method, it already is a functional interface (you can annotate it with `@FunctionalInterface` to have the compiler return an error when you add another method). What exactly is your question?

Comment: If you did that, the body of `CopyDataImpl` would become the body of a lambda in `CopyDataDynamicConfig#copyData`. This is still seemingly only a single use case for this interface, however. I'm struggling to find the benefit of this abstraction. You could just return a `Consumer<T>` and be rid of the `CopyData` interface.

Comment: You must declare as `public interface CopyData<T extends SpecificRecordBase> {
    void copy(T data);
}`, otherwise you cannot use a lambda expression

Comment: Why isn't the signature just `void copy(SpecificRecordBase data);`?

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel Thanks Yes I am aware I can mark it as functional interface but i am strugging to use it in my Configuration declaration :)

Comment: @Rogue Yes eventually I will use Consumer<T> interface as that will serve the purpose.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Your interface is already a functional interface by virtue of the fact that it has a single abstract method. You vaguely say you want to use it "seamlessly" - what exactly does this mean? In your comments you say you want to use it with your "Configuration declaration" - what does this refer to, as there is no mention of it in your question or code? Can you rephrase your question so it's clear what you're actually asking.

Comment: @knittl Thanks that helped, how can I use instance variable `copyDataProvider` then in lambda declaration ?

Comment: @jonhanson I want to use functional interface directly without creating an implementation class. I would like to see how can I achieve the same.

Comment: Functional interfaces are for short, quick functions that don't *need* a full class. You have a class that carries some state (`copyDataProvider`) whose method is 13 lines long and does some custom error handling. I would definitely *not* use the lambda syntax for that. It's far too complicated, *especially* the stateful part.

Comment: Thank you Slaw and  
Silvio Mayolo  for understanding my intent of the question. It really helped.

Comment: "_I am aware that I can make my interface functional interface easily as it has only method and can add @FunctionalInterface annotation_" – Just want to make sure this is clear. An interface can be a functional interface **even if that annotation is not present**. The only requirement is that the type is an interface, and it has exactly one abstract method (i.e., a SAM [Single Abstract Method] type). The `@FunctionalInterface` annotation only serves as documentation of intent and forcers the compiler to validate the type is a functional interface. It's similar to `@Override` in that regard.

Comment: @Slaw to be more precise, an interface that has exactly one abstract method that doesn’t match a `public` method in `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Yes I realised that it is best practice to use expressions over statements when employing functional programming and my method does mutation along with multiple statements. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try to rephrase the question:

> My question was I want to use functional interface directly and not using dedicated implementation class.

wants to ask: "how can I use a lambda expression instead of implementing the interface with a class?".

So basically, how to turn this:

```
public class CopyDataImpl implements CopyData {
    private CopyDataProvider copyDataProvider;

    @Override
    public <T extends SpecificRecordBase> void copy(T data) {
        try {
            Copier copier = copyDataProvider.copyFor(data);
            if(copier == null) {
                return;
            }
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Encoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(data.getSchema(), byteStream);
            data.customEncode(encoder);
            encoder.flush();
            copier.copy(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error occurred storing the data {}", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

@Configuration
public class CopyDataDynamicConfig {
    @Bean
    public CopyDataProvider copyDataProvider() {
        return new CopyDataProviderImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public CopyData copyData(CopyDataProvider copyDataProvider) {
        return new CopyDataImpl(copyDataProvider);
    }
}
```

into that:

```
@Configuration
public class CopyDataDynamicConfig {
    @Bean
    public CopyDataProvider copyDataProvider() {
        return new CopyDataProviderImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public <T> CopyData<T> copyData(CopyDataProvider copyDataProvider) {
        return data -> {
            try {
                Copier copier = copyDataProvider.copyFor(data);
                if(copier == null) {
                    return;
                }
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                Encoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(data.getSchema(), byteStream);
                data.customEncode(encoder);
                encoder.flush();
                copier.copy(data);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Error occurred storing the data {}", e.getMessage());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And the answer is that you must make your method non-generic (the interface can still be generic):

```
public interface CopyData<T extends SpecificRecordBase> {
    void copy(T data);
}
```

This is equivalent to `java.util.function.Consumer`:

```
public interface Consumer<T> {
  void accept(T t);
}
```

In your case, it's probably sufficient to define `interface CopyData { void copy(SpecificRecordBase data); }` without any generics.

Note that returning a lambda as a bean could break in weird ways. IIRC I ran into this problem once.

Be aware that you don't need to create a *named* class; you can easily create an anonymous class:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface CopyData {
    void copy(SpecificRecordBase data);
}

@Configuration
public class CopyDataDynamicConfig {
    @Bean
    public CopyDataProvider copyDataProvider() {
        return new CopyDataProviderImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public CopyData copyData(CopyDataProvider copyDataProvider) {
        return new CopyData() {
            @Override
            void copy(SpecificRecordBase data) {
                try {
                    Copier copier = copyDataProvider.copyFor(data);
                    if(copier == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    Encoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(data.getSchema(), byteStream);
                    data.customEncode(encoder);
                    encoder.flush();
                    copier.copy(data);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("Error occurred storing the data {}", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: For the general pattern, see also [Generic Interface vs Generic Methods, and when to use one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30575685/2711488)